# NextJS Image switch based on condition not working on production

Tags: reactjs, next.js, netlify

In my `nextjs`-application I have a `Header` with a logo, that needs to switch based on a condition. I use the [next/image](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image) component and the website is hosted by `netlify`.

```
const Header= () => {
   const [fullWidthBackground, setFullWidthBackground] = useState(false)
   const scrollPosition = useScrollPosition()

   useEffect(() => {
      const isFullWidth = document.body.classList.contains('full-width-hero-background')
      
      if (isFullWidth) {
         setFullWidthBackground(true)
       } else {
         setFullWidthBackground(false)
       }
     }, [fullWidthBackground])

   return (
     <div>
        <Link href={'/'}>
           <div
              className={`${
                 fullWidthBackground && scrollPosition === 0
                 ? 'flex items-center opacity-100'
                 : 'hidden opacity-0'
              }`}
           >
           <Image
               src="/white-logo.png"
               alt=""
               width={168}
               height={26}
          />
         </div>
         <div
            className={`${
               !fullWidthBackground || scrollPosition > 0
               ? 'flex items-center opacity-100'
               : 'hidden opacity-0'
            }`}
         >
          <Image
            src="/dark-logo.png"
            alt=""
            width={168}
            height={26}
          />
        </div>
      </Link>
     </div>
   )
})
```

This works only on `localhost` but when I run `npm run build` it doesn't work.

Can someone maybe help me out? Is it because of the `<Link>`?

Comment: Have you tried inspecting and seeing whether or not the image container have the right classes?

Comment: You need to tell us exactly what's happening, "it doesn't work" isn't helpful. Hosting on localhost and running `npm run build` are not mutually exclusive, does the build fail after running `npm run build` locally? Does the problem occur when hosting a production version locally with `npm run start`? Are there errors in the console? Please edit your question to provide those details.